# Qual a diferença entre criar um método e um bloco em uma classe do Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Eu tenho o costume de criar métodos dessa maneira no Ruby:

```
class MinhaClasse

  def metodo
    # meu método
  end

end
```

Mas às vezes encontramos por aí a criação direta de um bloco de código na classe:

```
class MinhaClasse

  bloco do
    # meu bloco
  end

end
```

Pra que serve isso? Qual a diferença disso e da criação de um método? Quando e por que deve ser usado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MinhaClasse
  def metodo
    # meu método
  end
end
```

O que está acontecendo aqui é bem simple: Você está criando um método de instancia na classe `MinhaClasse`. Nada fora do usual.

```
class MinhaClasse
  outro_metodo
end
```

Já quando você escreve isso, está chamando o método `outro_metodo` no objeto `self` do contexto. No caso, o `self` dentro do escopo da classe é a própria classe. Isso é equivalente a fazer `MinhaClasse.outro_metodo`.

Esse método poderia ter sido definido assim:

```
def MinhaClasse.outro_metodo
  # código
end
```

Ou assim, de forma equivalente:

```
class MinhaClasse
  def self.outro_metodo
    # código
  end
end
```

Claro, como qualquer outra invocação de método, você pode passar um bloco, e a implementação pode fazer o que quiser com o bloco, inclusive definir um método de instancia usando o bloco passado como a implementação dele. Algo assim:

```
class MinhaClasse
  def self.criar_metodo(&bloco)
    define_method(:metodo, &bloco)
  end

  criar_metodo do
    puts "oi!"
  end
end

obj = MinhaClasse.new
obj.metodo #=> "oi!"
```

Aqui usei o `define_method`, que é um método da classe `Class` para definir métodos a partir de um bloco. Pode-se até argumentar que `def metodo(a, b) ... end` seja um mero açúcar sintático para `define_method(:metodo) do |a, b| ... end`.

Quanto ao uso, metaprogramação! Isso permite que você crie sintaxes com comportamento "especial", e faça a linguagem se comportar como você quiser. Por exemplo:

```
class MyButton < Button
  on :click do
    puts "Me clicou!"
  end
end
```

Que poderia ser implementado como:

```
def Button.on(event, &handler)
  @@callbacks ||= {}
  @@callbacks[event] ||= []
  @@callbacks[event] << handler
end
```

Ou mesmo:

```
def Button.on(event, &handler)
  define_method("on_" + event, &handler)
end
```

Comment: Boa explicação. Sanou minhas dúvidas. Obrigado!